# How can I prevent a Gulp task with a dynamic import from being asynchronous?

Tags: import, promise, gulp, gulp-imagemin

I want to use gulp-imagemin to minify images. The relevant part of my gulpfile.js looks like this:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
// a couple more require('')s

function minifyImages(cb) {
    import('gulp-imagemin')
        .then(module => {
            const imagemin = module.default;
            gulp.src('src/img/**/*')
                .pipe(imagemin())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('img'));
            cb();
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            cb();
        });
}

function buildCSS(cb) { /* ... */ }

exports.build = gulp.series(buildCSS, minifyImages);
```

The reason I'm using a dynamic import here is because I think I have to - gulp-imagemin doesn't support the `require('')` syntax, and when I say `import imagemin from 'gulp-imagemin` I get an error saying "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

I would expect the `build` task to only finish after `minifyImages` has finished. After all, I'm calling `cb()` only at the very end, at a point where the promise should be resolved.

However, `build` seems to finish early, while `minifyImages` is still running. This is the output I get:

```
[21:54:47] Finished 'buildCSS' after 6.82 ms
[21:54:47] Starting 'minifyImages'...
[21:54:47] Finished 'minifyImages' after 273 ms
[21:54:47] Finished 'build' after 282 ms
<one minute later>
[21:55:49] gulp-imagemin: Minified 46 images (saved 5.91 MB - 22.8%)
```

How can I make sure the task doesn't finish early, and all tasks are run in sequence?

Let me know if there's something wrong with my assumptions; I'm somewhat new to gulp and importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are always asynchronous, so if the `cb()` callback is called just after creating the gulp stream as in your `then` handler, it's only obvious that the stream by that time has not finished yet (in fact, it hasn't even started).

The simplest solution to call a callback when the `gulp.dest` stream has finished is using [`stream.pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streampipelinestreams-callback), i.e.:

```js
function minifyImages(cb) {
    const { pipeline } = require('stream');
    return import('gulp-imagemin')
        .then(module => {
            const imagemin = module.default;
            pipeline(
                gulp.src('src/img/**/*'),
                imagemin(),
                gulp.dest('img'),
                cb
            );
        })
        .catch(cb);
}
```

Or similarly, with an async function.

```js
async function minifyImages(cb) {
    const { pipeline } = require('stream');
    const { default: imagemin } = await import('gulp-imagemin');
    return pipeline(
            gulp.src('src/img/**/*'),
            imagemin(),
            gulp.dest('img'),
            cb
    );
}
```

Another approach I have seen is to split the task in two sequential sub-tasks: the first sub-task imports the plugin module and stores it in a variable, and the second sub-task uses the plugin already loaded by the previous sub-task to create and return the gulp stream in the usual way.
Then the two sub-tasks can be combined with [`gulp.series`](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series/).

Comment: The second solution didn't seem to affect anything, but the first one first one worked like a charm, so thanks!

Comment: I am receiving `Callback must be a function. Received undefined` from these solutions.